# How do use Foreign Key in slug django

Tags: django

My Models:

```
class Faculty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty)


class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    faculty = models.ForeignKey(Faculty)
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program)
```

my Views

```
def profile(request, slug, faculty, program):
    template_name = 'profile.html'
    infor = get_object_or_404(Candidate, slug=slug, faculty=faculty, program=program)
    context = {'title': infor.name}
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

Urls

```
url(r'^(?P<faculty>[\w-]+)/(?P<program>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', profile, name='profile'),
```

Now I got the profile at host/1/1/sagar-devkota/ what I need is host/science/be/sagar-devkota/ Let assume science is a faculty and be is a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give slug field to both faculty and program model. And in filter use `__` for related lookups.

```
infor = get_object_or_404(Candidate, slug=slug, faculty__slug=faculty, program__slug=program)
```

you can do it by using with that `name` field too.

```
infor = get_object_or_404(Candidate, slug=slug, faculty__name=faculty, program__name=program)
```